# Why can Anaphylaxis lead to death?

Tags: allergies

Why can the immune system kill its host?

It is always better to just take up the insect poison, or peanut protein etc. instead to kill the host by preventing the breathing.

Is it just a modern symptom or did humans always have to fear death from anaphylaxis after an insect sting?